# Apache beam to read from kafka and to write to cassandra using windowing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, cassandra, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a requirement where I need to consume real time events from a kafka topic. The events are received as JSON messages. I need to convert each message into a key value pair and need to do a GroupbyKey. The output of GroupByKey is further processed by another ParDo. In this ParDo, I connect to cassandra table (in setup) and do some transformation. The output of this ParDo, is persisted to cassandra table. Pseudo code is

```
PCollection<String> kafkaEvents=KafkaIO.read()
PCollection<KV<String,Event>> keyValuePair=kafkaEvents.apply(ParDo.of(new ConverToKV())))
PCollection<KV<String,Iterable<Event>>> groupedPCol=keyValuePar.apply(GroupByKey.create()))
PCollection<CassandraEntity> cassandraEntity=groupedPCol.apply(ParDo.of(new TransformToEntity())
```

TransformToEntity

```
 @setup
 setup(){
  cluster = createCassandraCluster()
 }
 processElement(){
   dataFromCassandra = cluster.getSession.execute("Cassandra Query")
   CassandraEntity casEntity=processElementUsinngDataFromCassandra()
   processContext.output(casEntity)
}
@teardown
tearDown(){
 cluster.close()
}
```

The operation is executed with a fixed window of size 30seconds. The events are supposed to come from Kafka at a rate of 500 events/sec. But this pipeline, when run on google dataflow did not work at all. It will always throw Cassandra BusyPoolException when multiple worker nodes are involved.

Any help in solving this is highly appreciated.

EDIT
I cannot copy the whole stack trace. It is the below exception

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed  Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)))
```

It is thrown on the line in setup method where I instantiate the cluster

Comment: could you add more information about your cassandra stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is for you to make your Cassandra Cluster object (or maybe even the Session object) into a static variable, so that you will not create new ones for every individual thread.

**Why?** Cassandra Session objects are thread safe. Furthermore, streaming pipelines have hundreds of threads **per worker**, so you must have many many connections.

In short:

```
class CassandraWritingDoFn extends DoFn<....> {
  private static Cluster cassandraCluster = null;

  @Setup
  public void setup(...) {
    if (CassandraWritingDoFn.cassandraCluster == null) {
      CassandraWritingDoFn.cassandraCluster = createCluster();
    }
  }
}
```

This should have a single cluster instance for each worker that will be shared by all worker threads, and save you on connection parallelism.

Comment: Let me try this out and comeback. Thank you for the reply

Comment: I have tried this out. BusyPoolException has gone. But consumption is very slow. Tried reducing windo duration to 5 secods. Still its very slow. I am using fixed windows with 5 seconds duration and allowed lateness of 30 seconds.

Comment: how many elements are you seeing? And why are you windowing your data?

Comment: I am trying to consume around 500 messages/sec. Windowing is done because I have a groupby operation to perform